# static library linkage failure in visual c

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-libraries, static-linking

In visual c++, I created a static library with two files, myLib.h and myLib.cpp. I also have a console application project with the file testSequence.cpp that references this library.
Within myLib.h I have defined a class `template<class prec> class sequence` which has the function declaration `prec *getPrimes(int numToGet)` this function is then defined in myLib.cpp. However, when I build testSequence, there is a linking error, and it says `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int * __thiscall mathLib::sequence<int>::getPrimes(int)" (?getPrimes@?$sequence@H@mathLib@@QAEPAHH@Z) referenced in function "char * __cdecl codeString(char *,char *,bool)" (?codeString@@YAPADPAD0_N@Z)`
So, yeah, help would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl.html) for an explanation of the error.

Basically, what you're trying to do cannot be done. The compiler must be able to *see* the implementation of the class template when it tries to instantiate it for a given template type parameter. You need to move the implementations for all the member functions to the header file.

Comment: Crap, I was afraid of this. But isn't this a popular enough framework that there would be some sort of work around? Thank you!

Comment: @bathtub Afraid not, *export* was the C++98 solution to this problem, but it was removed from C++11. You might be able to get some limited functionality using C++11's [extern templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Extern_template). You might be able to explicitly instantiate `sequence` for some set of types in your cpp file; and then declare the type as an *extern template* in the source files of the users of your library. No idea whether this will work.

Comment: Dropping the template seems like the best solution for my use, thanks anyway.